# How to Check a String in Java with an Zero Character RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

The following piece of code checks for same variable portion `/en(^$|.*)` which is empty or any characters.  So the expression should match `/en` AND `/en/bla`, `/en/blue` etc. 
But the expression doesn't work when checking for just `/en`.

```
"/en".matches("/en(^$|.*)")
```

Is there a way to make this empty regex check (^$) perform with java?

**edit**

I mean: Is there a way to make this piece of code return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're currently doing is checking whether `en` is followed by the start of string then the end of string (which doesn't make sense, since the start of string needs to be first) or anything else. This should work:

```
"/en".matches("/en(|.*)")
```

Or just using `?` (optional):

```
"/en".matches("/en(.*)?")
```

But it's rather pointless, since `*` is zero or more (so a blank string will match for `.*`), just this should do it:

```
"/en".matches("/en.*")
```

**EDIT:**

Your code was already returning true, but it was not matching the `^$` part, but rather `.*` (similar to the above).

I should point out that you may as well use `startsWith`, unless your real data is more complex:

```
"/en".startsWith("/en")
```

Comment: `(|.*)` == `(.*)?` == `(.*)`

Comment: @DuncanJones If you use `matches` capturing groups have no purpose that I know of. And I'm sure OP can add it back if he/she needs it.

Comment: Using your thought the final regex would become something like this. (|\\/.*$). thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dukeling Good point, I was forgetting `matches` was being used.

Comment: @justastefan Hard to tell, unless you tell us what the final purpose of the regex is!

Comment: @justastefan `"/en".matches("/en(|.*)")` is completely equivalent to `"/en".matches("/en.*")`.

Comment: i used it like this: "/en(|\\/.*$)" in order to match /en and /en/<random stuff>

Comment: @justastefan Again, your pattern is more complicated than it needs to be. Why are you not just using `"/en.*"` as we keep trying to explain? You've asked for our help, but then altered the correct answer!

Comment: @justastefan How about `"/en(/.*)?"`?

Answer (score 3):

> **Is there a way to make this piece of code return true?**
>
> ```
> "/en".matches("/en(^$|.*)")
> ```

That code *does* return true. Just try it!

However, your pattern is unnecessarily complex. Try:

```
"/en".matches("/en.*")
```

This will match `/en` followed by anything (including nothing).